# Adding a listener to the Ext.js create store is raising an error

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, listeners

I'm using Ext.js to try and fill an accordion panel with stores.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: jobStatusModel,
                storeId: jobStatusDescription,
                sortOnLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'http://server/JobScheduler/Service.svc/JobScheduler/Jobs/' + jobStatusDescription,
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json'
                    }
                },
                autoLoad: true,
                listeners: {
                    load: fillItemsAndSetPanelTitle
                }
            });
```

This is embedded in a loop that runs for each "job status."

Outside of this loop I have the `fillItemsAndSetPanelTitle` function.

Whenever I remove the "listeners" from the create store, it runs fine. But otherwise, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I've found that it complains because I'm calling my main function "manually."

Previously, it used:

```
  this.control({
        "#MainMenuPanel": {
            render: this.onMainMenuPanelRender
        }
    });
```

I wanted to wait for my stores to load before calling `onMainMenuPanelRender`, but adding the `"this.control"` call in the function that waited until all stores were loaded didn't seem to work, so I called it "manually" `(this.onMainMenuPanelRender())`.

So I guess my question is now: how can I call `"this.control"` outside of the initial "init" function?

Comment: Why would you call this.control outside of controller.init ? All it does is setting up the controller. It would not make sense elsewhere. I think you are looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call this.control outside of controller.init ? All it does is setting up the controller. It would not make sense elsewhere. I think you are looking in the wrong direction.

Also it is recommended to use Ext.define to define your stores at application load time. At the same time make the function fillItemsAndSetPanelTitle a member of the controller. I don't know what ' fill items ' does, but if you would use a grid panel for displaying the store, the grid would populate itself automatically when the store loads.

Another issue I see with your code is that you set the panel title when the store is loaded, but before the panel is created. I think the correct order would be : load the stores, get the panel titles, create the panels directly with the correct headers.

I recommend you to read the documentation about the MVC pattern in ExtJs. It will release you from many headaches.